# Folder Download URL Box API

Tags: box

Hope someone can help me out here

I have a folder already created on my box account that I want to fetch the `download_url` for,

I am making the following call:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/"folder_id"?fields=sync_state,shared_link 

'Authorization': 'Bearer <token_id>'
```

With the following parameters:

```
{"shared_link": {"access": "open", "permissions": {"can_preview": true, "can_download": true}}, "marked_for_sync": "synced"}
```

I get back:

```
{"type":"folder","id":"folder_id","etag":"0","sync_state":"not_synced","shared_link":{"url":"https:\/\/app.box.com\/s\/qkzyovqm0dhgt9zaluxl","download_url":null,"vanity_url":null,"is_password_enabled":false,"unshared_at":null,"download_count":0,"preview_count":0,"access":"open","permissions":{"can_download":true,"can_preview":true}}}
```

Why is there no download_url?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I lodged a ticket with Box to resolve this.

This was their reply:

> The folder is not actually meant to have download url. It only
>   happens on a file level. So if you make the call for the file with the
>   same parameters, the download url will show up. It wont show for a
>   folder level call.

I pointed to http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-update-information-about-a-folder
and the example response that shows a download_url that lead me on this merry chase.

Comment: Yes, in box there is no option to download entire folder content with a download url!!!